# failed to open stream: No such file or directory with webpage

Tags: php

I'm trying to read a small part of a webpage. At first I thought the problem was `urlencode` so added that but the problem still arises.

The script reads fine from simple links like google.com however it isn't working with the link I want.

```
<?php 
        $link = "http://www.adidas.co.uk/nmd_r1-bape-camouflage-shoes/BA7326.html";
        $newlink = urlencode($link);

        $linkcontents = file_get_contents($newlink);
        $needle = "Sold out";
        if(strpos($linkcontents, $needle) == true){
            echo "String found";
        } else{
            echo "String not found";
        } ?>
```

Comment: There's no need using `urlencode`

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but it still brings up a different error.  "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in <path>"

Answer (score 2):

Im changing my answer because i did this below code:

```
$link = "http://www.adidas.co.uk/nmd_r1-bape-camouflage-shoes/BA7326.html";

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

die(var_dump($output));
```

and it gave me this response

> Sorry, you have been blocked
>
> You are unable to access this website
>
> **Why have I been blocked?**
>
> This website is using a security service to protect itself from online
>   attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security
>   solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block
>   including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or
>   malformated data.
>
> **What can I do to resolve this?**
>
> If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an
>   anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with
>   malware.
>
> If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network
>   administrator to run a scan across the network looking for
>   misconfigured or infected devices.
>
> HTTP 403 - Forbidden "

It seems you are unable to do any webscraping on the Addidas website.

Comment: Thanks man! I never used cURL before so I'll need to get used it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @bsaid97 No problem, if you REALLY need to use the addidas website i think you can access the information that youre after through their API: https://developers.adidas.com/ | If youve never used an API before it can be a bit confusing but wih a little research im sure youll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `urlencode`.

The site you are trying to access responds with `403 Forbidden`.

```
file_get_contents(http://www.adidas.co.uk/nmd_r1-bape-camouflage-shoes/BA7326.html): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

This is because `file_get_contents` doesn't send a properly formed request from the site's perspective.

You should use **curl** or another request tool such as **Guzzle**, and send a properly formed request that is understand by the site you are trying to scrape (Eg: Guzzle will send some headers by default so it should work).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the remote host is filtering out connections without valid header information (e.g. like user-agent).

You can spoof it (usually better to use cURL for these things) by creating a [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php):

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36\r\n"
  )
);

$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);

$content = file_get_contents($url,false,$ctx);
```

Disclaimer: While this may work in returning the HTML, the fact that the remote host put these checks in place may indicate that doing this would go against their terms of use. Don't blame me if your IP gets blacklisted.